# How to unlock a ReentrantLock Object when exception happens before unlock is called

Tags: java

In the below If exception happens at syncMethod2() then how can i unlock the lock object?

```
public class ReEntrantLock {
ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

void syncMethod1() {
  lock.lock();
  syncMethod2(); // throw new NullPointerException();
  lock.unlock();
}

}
```

Comment: By the way: I suggest you choose different names for your testing classes, as similar names (or worse: identical names) to the classes you're handling can become confusing and produce unexpected results. Appending "Test" to the name is usually enough to make it safer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `try`-`finally`:

```
lock.lock();
try {
    syncMethod2(); // throw new NullPointerException();
} finally {
    lock.unlock();
}
```

That pattern is also described in [the `ReentrantLock` JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html).

Answer (score 7):

```
public class ReEntrantLock {
    ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    void syncMethod1() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            syncMethod2();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

}
```

It's right there in the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) ...